# How to import and read multiple large .csv files into a table in an SQL database using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, large-data

So, I have a **large amount of data** that I wish to upload on a table in MySQL. I can use MySQL's inbuilt data import wizard to upload each .csv file(**around 90 files, ~150 mb each**) into the table but each file takes too long and it will take months to upload all this data.

So instead, I want to use the ***'LOAD DATA INFILE'*** command(which apparently is faster according to the internet) in MySQL but this is generally done for individual files, so I was wondering if I can maybe **'loop'** this SQL command using Python(Python has a module that connects to MySQL named 'MySQLclient') and run it through the directory where each of my data file is in so that all the data gets uploaded on to my table one by one automatically. But unfortunately I am not able to come up with a syntactically accurate method to do so in Python 3.6. Maybe you can help?

Other methods/commands to perform this task are also welcome.

*Versions: Python 3.6; MySQL 5.7; Win 8.1;*

Comment: you can use pandas to [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and to insert into db  using [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: just do it - it works as you described

Comment: Um ok, maybe some help with the syntax will help, because I know what to do. A line or two of code that loops an SQL command and runs through each .csv file in a folder in order , without me naming each file.

Comment: split your tasks in smaller then its clear - read all csv files in dir into list; then loop over list ... etc

Comment: ok, I found the glob directory to list the files. Maybe now something will do

Comment: thanks @raviraja for the info, I think I am on the right track now, I am going to make multiple dataframes and concatenate them into one single frame and then use 'to_sql' to transfer this data frame to MySQL server.